# Need JSON-LD Structured Data Example for Multiple Courses

Tags: json-ld, structured-data

I have referred to the following example [given by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/course):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Introduction to Computer Science and Programming</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Course",
      "name": "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming",
      "description": "Introductory CS course laying out the basics.",
      "provider": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "University of Technology - Eureka",
        "sameAs": "http://www.ut-eureka.edu"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I have a page with list of Soft Skill Courses. Google also gives something called `ItemList`, but no example has been given on how to put it together with the `Course`. How can I specify multiple Courses structured data in JSON-LD? Thanks!

Comment: https://schema.org/CourseInstance helped me. "An instance of a Course which is distinct from other instances because it is offered at a different time or location or through different media or modes of study or to a specific section of students."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It is enough to open one more script like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Course",
  "name": "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming",
  "description": "Introductory CS course laying out the basics.",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "University of Technology - Eureka",
    "sameAs": "http://www.ut-eureka.edu"
  }
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Course",
  "name": "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming",
  "description": "Introductory CS course laying out the basics.",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "University of Technology - Eureka",
    "sameAs": "http://www.ut-eureka.edu"
  }
}
</script>
```